# Binding a directive through changed values

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i am new to angular and i have searched a lot for an answer that resolves my problem.

I have tow directives 'ms-list' and 'ms-view'. In a specific screen 'ms-list' appears inside 'ms-view' and it displays data according to passed parameters from view controller to the list directive through scope.

When this screens loads for the first time, 'ms-list' displays data just fine. When you alter the property that works as a parameter in the list directive, it doesn't do anything.

View Directive

```
 angular
.module('app.core')
.controller('MsViewController', MsViewController)
.directive('msView', msViewDirective);

function MsViewController($http, $scope) {
var vm = this;
  //function to change the parameter's value
  function changeParam(param) {
     vm.selectedParam = param;
  }
}

function msViewDirective() {
   return {
     restrict: 'E',
     require: 'msView',
     controller: 'MsViewController as MsView',
     templateUrl: 'app/core/directives/ms-view/ms-view.html',
     compile: function (tElement) {
       // Add class
       tElement.addClass('ms-view');
       return function postLink(scope, iElement) {
         // Data
       };
    }
  };
}
```

in the 'ms-view' html file i call the 'ms-list' directive and pass a parameter that is changing through the function 'changeParam' in the view controller i showed above.

```
<ms-list object="MsView.selectedParam"></ms-generic-list>
```

List Directive

```
 angular
.module('app.core')
.controller('MsListController', MsListController)
.directive('msList', msListDirective);

function MsListController($state, $http, $scope) {
   var vm = this;
   vm.params = {
     "object": $scope.object,
   };

   //Function to fetch data according to params list
   fetchData(vm.params);
}

function msListDirective() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    transclude : true,
    scope: {
      object: '='
    },
    controller: 'MsListController as MsList',
    templateUrl: 'app/core/directives/ms-list/ms-list.html',
    compile: function (tElem, tAttrs) {
      tAttrs.$observe('object', function (data) {
          console.log("changed value = " + data);
      }, true);
      // Add class
      tElem.addClass('ms-list');
    }
  };
}
```

While observing the parameter 'object' inside compile function it appears to be taking the correct value every time i change it. The problem is that i don't know how to trigger the function inside list controller so as to fetch the new data according to the changed value.

As i mentioned i am new to angular so i don't know if my implementation is the best one.

Thank you.

Comment: You can do $scope.$watch('object', func)

Comment: The controller for a directive is really a way to define an object that creates an interface for other directives to require your directive and take actions on it's scope or otherwise "set" things on it.  Using $scope.$watch or attrs.$observe will both have the effect of letting you know when the value has been changed so just move the functionality you currently have written in the controller for the directive into the directive's link function.  Really you typically want the link function since there you have access to the scope for each instance of the directive the link function is run.

Comment: Thank you staskus!!! I never thought it would be too easy!